# Ubuntu 14.04: script not running in /etc/network/if-up.d

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, scripts, network-manager

[wireless-info pasteit](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24213926/)

I am trying to have Ubuntu run this script in /etc/network/if-up.d/ to bring up my wireless AP via hostapd once the eth0 network is up:

```
    #!/bin/sh # filename: ap_up.sh 
    /home/adp/bin/ap_ctl --start | tee /home/adp/bin/log/ap_ctl_start.txt 
    /home/adp/bin/ap_ctl --ics | tee /home/adp/bin/log/ap_ctl_ics.txt
```

However, I have spaces between each of those lines, but I can't figure out how to paste it as-written using this code format.  sh ignores white space, yeah?

Once logged in to adp (non root), no logs have been created - and confirmed with ifconfig - the wlan0 isn't up and the script wasn't ran.

I can manually execute the script (while root, obviously) and it will bring up the interface fine. I just can't get Ubuntu to do it and I think it has something to do with ap_up.sh is located in root and adp doesn't have access to root. Am I on the right track?

UPDATE: moved script to `/usr/local/bin` and corrected all the filepaths and rebooted.  This time it hung up on the Ubuntu boot splash screen saying it will wait an additional 60 seconds to wait for a network configuration, later saying it will boot without full network config.

My --start log looked fine and the `wlan0` looks fine in `ifconfig`.  `iwconfig` shows that it's up and in Master mode...but my phone can't see it.

`/var/log/hostapd.log` looked like this:

```
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 56: DEPRECATED: 'dump_file' configuration variable is not used anymore
ctrl_interface_group=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: TDLS external setup
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:10
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:8
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:9
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:13
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:11
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:12
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlan0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x1086790
nl80211: Register frame type=0xb0 nl_handle=0x1086790 match=
nl80211: Register frame command failed (type=176): ret=-114 (Operation already in progress)
nl80211: Register frame match - hexdump(len=0): [NULL]
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=3)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x1085d90)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x1085d90)
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan0
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x10897b0 (wlan0))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=(nil) drv_priv=(nil) -> hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0x1085d90)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x10897b0
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x1085d90)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x1085d90)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x1085d90
```

My --ics is to bring up my iptables and it reported `networking stop/pre-start, process 810'

Any ideas now?

Comment: At the time the boot/startup runs the things in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`, you (`adp`) are not logged in. If you have an encrypted home directory, `/home/adp` is not available. Put the script (and the logs) in a permanently available directory, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: That raises another thought: on boot is Ubuntu technically running as root or is it running as no user?  If running at root, it should be able to access any users' directories?

Comment: OK, now the script will run.  It brings up the interface just fine, but appears to throw an error in the script command telling it to bring up the iptables.

Comment: See update above